# Could Markdown and mini-Markdown have the same support for backticks?

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, code-formatting

In comments, mini-Markdown *sometimes* has a different syntax for backticks within backticks: when the code starts and/or ends with a backtick, one needs escaping. In those cases, could mini-Markdown also support adding one space to the delimiters, just like Markdown does?

Markdown:

1. Use any unique number of backticks in the delimiter to allow for (other sequences of) backticks in the code itself:
   ````` ```code with `embedded```` backticks``` `````
   yields
   ````` code with `embedded```` backticks `````.
2. Add one additional space to the delimiters above if the code fragment starts and/or ends with backticks, [just as documented](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code):
   ````` `` `code with `embedded```` backticks` `` ````` and ``` Perl's `` $` `` ```
   yield
   ````` `code with `embedded```` backticks` ````` and Perl's `` $` ``.

Mini-Markdown (for comments):

1. [Same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UXVP.png) as in Markdown<sup>†</sup>.
2. The Markdown extra-space [does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2NWP.png). Instead, this [requires](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRGPx.png) single opening and closing backticks, and escaping of all embedded backticks:
   ``` `\`code with \`embedded\`\`\`\` backticks\`` ``` and ``` `$\`` ```.

I realize that the current escaping should always be supported to preserve the existing comments. But maybe mini-Markdown could *also* support the extra space.

<sup>†</sup> One *could* also escape, like `` `code with \`embedded\`\` backticks` ``, which however does not work in Markdown. Until today, I thought this escaping was required in comments. But today I realized that Markdown and mini-Markdown behave *almost* the same.